# Native Page Transitions Ionic 5 - overlay transition

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have been using the Native Page Transitions package by Telerik in my Ionic 5 app successfully. I understand it is deprecated but, with the update to capacitor 3, this plugin is causing with Android, specifically, the slide animation doesn't work as expected as there is a flash of the splash screen while the transition happens.

Are there any alternatives to this package? I am trying to achieve a transition similar to the video below, where as opposed to a regular push across, the page comes as an overlay above the previous page nearly.

[image]

Comment: It's a shame capacitor can't get this basic stuff right. We had to use Flutter in the end :-/. Did you find a solution?